# Can someone please explain what MARS for Logical Connection means or how does it work? Also what is Lock Timeout/sec is? I am new to it.

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

Can someone please explain what MARS for Logical Connection means or how does it work? Also what is Lock Timeout/sec is? I am new to it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mars+sql&oq=mars+sql

Comment: The title is your opportunity to *summarize* your question. The body of your question is your opportunity to *elaborate* on precisely what you're asking for, what research you've already done, etc. An identical title + body is rarely if ever correct. And don't put fluff like "Can someone please explain" in. A simpler "What is X?" or "What does X mean?" might be good titles, so long as, as I say, the body of the question elaborates. And provided the question itself isn't too broad.

Comment: Before asking such question, please, do some research, and after you have read several articles about the subject, come back and ask if you have any question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0):

The *Tabular Data Stream* (TDS) protocol invented by Sybase and extended by Microsoft **requires** that the client read the *entire results* of each operation before continuing on to the next operation.  Failure to do so provokes a "results pending" error.  Prior to MARS, the only way to interleave two concurrent operations was with two independent database connections.  The server even offers ways to associate two connections to let them share certain resources.

Sybase used to insist that it had engineered its DBMS to make connections cheap, and encouraged application developers to use as many as were convenient.  Other DBMSs did not follow that lead: they use multiplexed connections (presumably of heavier weight) and recommended one connection per application.

That "do it all" requirement is unique to TDS among DBMS client-server protocols.  Code written for, say, Oracle -- that assumes a new operation can be begun while results are left pending on the server -- will fail when ported to SQL Server.  Because this aspect of TDS is somewhat arcane, it tends to surprise programmers when they first encounter it.

There is a tendency to view errors that occur on one system and not on another as a shortcoming, not simply a design choice. Microsoft introduced MARS to overcome this perceived shortcoming.  IIRC, it didn't change the underlying TDS protocol, but rather introduced a 1:N mapping of database handles to database connections.

There's no advantage -- none -- to using MARS, unless you want the multiplexed connection compatibility because you *know* your SQL will be used on other DBMSs.  Otherwise, you're better off pretending it doesn't exist, as was the case, successfully, for 2 decades.

You will find more information on the [FreeTDS](https://www.freetds.org) website.

Comment: Thanks James. Unfortunately I can not open FreeTDS website for security reasons. Could you please give a brief idea how it works?